# Can you use the AddNew method to add a field to an empty recordset in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a copy of a recordset and starting with a blank recordset to do so. Can I use the AddNew method to populate the field names, or is there a different way that has to happen? Thanks.

Comment: What is a Recordset in your context? You need to show what kind of object that is and what is the source of the data. I assume it's not a DataTable. `ADODB` instead of `ADO.Net`, maybe?

Comment: ADODB recordsets, sorry.

Comment: Do you actually need to use `ADODB` instead of `ADO.Net` (or Entity Framework or an simpler ORM)? Is this a VB.Net app or a VB6 app? Migration? Post some code that can show what you're dealing with. Note that this question has already been asked a gazillion times ~everywhere.